# Как можно поднять slick-dots в slick-slider?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, slick.js

Как можно разместить slick-dots таким образом? То есть прямо на слайдер наслоить? Через абсолютное позиционирование?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавляйте всегда ваш код, чтобы вам дали готовый пример и чтобы не утруждать отвечающих

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте элементу `.slick-dots` в CSS значение `bottom` с положительным значением. Это должно поднять элемент наверх.